# Boost program_options trailing slash and space in path not parsing correctly

Tags: c++, boost

I am not proficient in C++.  I have inherited a Visual Studio 2017 C++ command-line program on Windows that makes use of Boost's program_options:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

    struct Options
    {
        std::string input;
        std::string output;
        std::string xmlfilter;
    };

        Options opts;
        po::options_description desc("OPTIONS");
        desc.add_options()
            ("input,i", po::value<string>(&opts.input)->required(), "input file")
            ("output,o", po::value<string>(&opts.output)->required(), "output folder path")
            ("xmlfilter,x", po::value<string>(&opts.filter)->implicit_value(""), "enable XML filtering (optionally specify config file)")

        po::variables_map vm;
        store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
```

When the output folder path has a space in the name, in Windows it must be double-quoted.
At my management's direction, the program must also allow the output path to have a trailing backslash or not at the user's option.
When the command line looks like:

```
exename -i inputfile -o "output path\" -x
```

the variable map has the wrong results.

vm.count("output") is true (which is correct) and opts.output is "output path\" -x" (which is wrong).

vm.count("xmlfilter") is false (which is wrong).

I understand what Boost is doing and why, but online searching isn't yielding a fix, and I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific syntax your are using with Boost here, I usually use the vm["output"].as< std::string >() syntax.  However, from what I see, your issue doesn't appear to be with Boost, but rather the Windows command prompt.

When you enter the command:

```
.\a.exe -i inputfile -o "output path\" -x
```

The ending double quote after path is being escaped by the \ character.  Using two \ characters seems to fix your issue as far as I understand it.  However, if you absolutely can't use \\ in place of \ I’m not sure what to tell you.

```
.\a.exe -i inputfile -o "output path\\" -x
```

Here is my output with the single \

```
>.\a.exe -i inputfile -o "output path\" -x
1  .\a.exe
2  -i
3  inputfile
4  -o
5  output path" -x

opts.output =
vm.count("output") = 1
vm("output").as<std::string>() = output path" -x
vm.count("xmlfilter") = 0
```

And here it is with the double \

```
>.\a.exe -i inputfile -o "output path\\" -x
1  .\a.exe
2  -i
3  inputfile
4  -o
5  output path\
6  -x

opts.output =
vm.count("output") = 1
vm("output").as<std::string>() = output path\
vm.count("xmlfilter") = 1
```

For reference here is the code I ran (a little different from yours), which prints data directly from the argv input array in main.

```cpp
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

struct Options
{
    std::string input;
    std::string output;
    std::string xmlfilter;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    Options opts;
    po::options_description desc("OPTIONS");
    desc.add_options()
        ("input,i", po::value<string>(&opts.input)->required(), "input file")
        ("output,o", po::value<string>(&opts.output)->required(), "output folder path")
        ("xmlfilter,x", po::value<string>(&opts.xmlfilter)->implicit_value(""), "enable XML filtering (optionally specify config file)")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        cout << i+1 << "  " << argv[i] << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "opts.output = " << opts.output << endl;
    cout << "vm.count(\"output\") = " << vm.count("output") << endl;
    cout << "vm(\"output\").as<std::string>() = " << vm["output"].as<std::string>() << endl;
    cout << "vm.count(\"xmlfilter\") = " << vm.count("xmlfilter") << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You are correct on two counts.  It is Windows and not Boost that is causing the problem.  Also, using 2 backslashes does not cause the problem.  After spending 2 days trying various hacks with no success, we have had to give up.  We're going to put a more descriptive error message and leave it at that.  Thanks for taking a look.